# java - Make first digits of txt file as file name, and the rest of file as text in the same file

Tags: java, windows, file, parsing

Im trying to create a java txt reader, that will read the first 10 digits and make ia as the file name as;
input:

`S00000050 - Some text 1.`

`S00000060 - Some other text 2.
 with other text the goes with it`

Output:

S00000050.c with the `/* some text 1*/` as a comment in it.

S00000060.c with the `/* some other text 2 with other text the goes with it`*/` as a comment in it.

The problem is that i can't limit my parse method to go from the first S00... til the second S00...as also creating a file name based on the text readed.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was supposed to be different names, i will edit. thaks

Comment: if read the whole line and use `substring(0, 10)` to fetch the first 10 characters. then you can use `substring(10)` to get the comment (might need to adjust the numbers)

Answer (score 0):

If there is extension method feature in Java, it would be more easier. Anyway

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

class MyFile extends File{
    String fileNameAndComment;
    public MyFile(String fileNameAndComment){
        super(fileNameAndComment.split("-")[0]);
        this.fileNameAndComment = fileNameAndComment;
    }
    public void writeComment(){
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(this);
            fw.write("/*"+fileNameAndComment.split("-")[1]+"*/");
            fw.close();// finally block? I don't want to code to be longer than this is. So just close here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.asList("S00000060 - Some other text 2","S00000050 - Some text 1").stream().map(x->new MyFile(x))
                .forEach(x->{
                    x.writeComment(); //not sure I should do this or inside the constructor
                });
            }


}
```